# Normal map cannot be baked properly

Tags: normal-map, blend-files

[image]I am trying to bake normal map but this does not work.
The half of map is broken.

Please help me.[image]

Comment: How does the UV map look like?

Comment: I added UV map. Thank you.

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: sorry I tried to share my file in different ways but it didn't work somehow.